# Сложность в создании оператора (for) в Assembly

Tags: ассемблер

Регистр R4 имеет у меня значение 4221, регистр R5 имеет значение 0. Как мне в Assembly сделать так, чтобы к регистру R5 постоянно прибавлялось по единице пока он не достигнет значения регистра R4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так подсказывает базовая логика (ассемблеров разных, кстати, немало):

```
@@start:
  inc r5
  cmp r5, r4
  jne @@start
```